# Setting Default SQLite3 Fields Dynamically

Tags: sqlite, command

I have an SQLite3 database that I would like to create. I want an INTEGER field (named "Length") to have a DEFAULT value that equals the length of the string in another field (named "Pattern").

```
CREATE TABLE knowledge (
    Entry INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT,
    Priority TINYINT UNSIGNED   CHECK (0 <= Priority < 15),
    Pattern TEXT   NOT NULL,
    Length INTEGER UNSIGNED   DEFAULT 'LENGTH(Pattern);'
);
```

However, the current table set-up does not "dynamically" set the value of "Length" as desired.

How can I properly set the DEFAULT value of "Length" to be the string length of the "Pattern" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Default value you want to assign is dynamic which sqlite does not support. One solution is what CL. said. I would define the default value as 0 and use not one but two triggers (one for insert and another for update).

```
CREATE TRIGGER default_length_on_insert AFTER INSERT ON knowledge WHEN NEW.Length IS 0
BEGIN
UPDATE knowledge SET Length=length(NEW.Pattern) WHERE ROWID = NEW.ROWID;
END;
```

and

```
CREATE TRIGGER default_length_on_update AFTER UPDATE ON knowledge
BEGIN
UPDATE knowledge SET Length=length(NEW.Pattern) WHERE ROWID = NEW.ROWID;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the idea of having two TRIGGERs.

Answer (score 1):

A default value must be a constant.

You coud use a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER knowledge_length_default
AFTER INSERT ON knowledge
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.Length IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE knowledge
    SET Length = length(NEW.Pattern)
    WHERE Entry = NEW.Entry;
END;
```